# Proportionality check for samples at different scales

Tags: proportion

*(I am not a stat guy so kindly excuse my lack of knowledge)*

There are two systems A & B that are counting vehicles at a particular road junction. System A is expected to capture more vehicles than system B. However, it is expected the vehicle counts from both systems are proportional throughout the day. Below is the count of vehicles recorded for each hour of the day using  systems A (count_A) and B (count_B) at a junction. I have calculated the ratio to check if it remains more or less same throughout the day.

```
    hour count_B count_A    ratio_nan
    1   59.00000    653     0.09035
    2   54.00000    573     0.09424
    3   56.00000    555     0.10090
    4   98.00000    640     0.15313
    5   140.00000   937     0.14941
    6   137.00000   1946    0.07040
    7   139.00000   3284    0.04233
    8   143.00000   4540    0.03150
    9   147.00000   4449    0.03304
    10  142.00000   4100    0.03463
    11  129.00000   3978    0.03243
    12  146.00000   3752    0.03891
    13  155.00000   3789    0.04091
    14  136.00000   3761    0.03616
    15  151.00000   3964    0.03809
    16  110.00000   4054    0.02713
    17  96.00000    4224    0.02273
    18  82.00000    4439    0.01847
    19  63.00000    3494    0.01803
    20  37.00000    2740    0.01350
    21  33.00000    2001    0.01649
    22  21.00000    1512    0.01389
    23  20.00000    1169    0.01711
    24  3.00000     831     0.00361
```

[image] [image]

Ideally the plotted line (top figure) for ratio across different hours of the day should be horizontally straight indicating direct proportionality between counts from the two datasets. However, there is a spike during morning hours indicating disproportionality in the vehicle counts.

There are some 1500 such junctions and I want to check for each junction how much similiar/proportional are the vehicle count values from both systems. Does Pearson correlation provide a good measure to test the proportionality in this case?  How can I statistically determine for each junction whether the recorded values from both systems are proportional?

Comment: Not well. Pearson correlation is measuring how well a straight line say $y = a + bx$ approximates the data. You explicitly want to know how well proportionality $y = bx$ approximates the data, which is a different question. Measuring how well it works is better done directly by looking at the ratio, or even better in some ways its logarithm.

Comment: @Nick Cox Thanks for your comment. Do you have an idea about my second questions "How can I statistically determine for each junction whether the recorded values from both systems are proportional?" Each station will have 24 records, one for each hour. Is there any comparison test to determine how well proportionality approx. these data ?

Comment: The ratio `count_A/count_B` can be calculated so long as the denominator is positive. The stability of the ratio can be measured by its standard deviation, or -- possibly even better -- by the SD of the logarithm of the ratio. You could fit lines of the form $y = bx$ and assess how well they fit. I wouldn't want to turn this into a statistical testing problem. Many people would want to turn this into fitting one over-arching model and then looking for the biggest departures. If you don't know about them, that may be more complicated than you want.

Comment: This can't be a new problem in traffic engineering, I would guess, but I have no idea about relevant literature.

Comment: @Nick Cox,  thanks again for your comment. they are indeed valuable. I plotted the SD but would also do SD of the log of the ratio.  I am not aware but would like to learn about what you mentioned "fitting one overarching model" just out of curiousity. If you have related literature do direct me.

Comment: A model fit requires that you're thinking about predicting one count from the other. I guess it then could be a generalised linear model with indicator variables for each junction, log link, Poisson family, and no intercept.  I would ask a different question as people interested in such topics might not look at a question on correlations.

Comment: yeah makes sense.  perhaps 'proportionality check for samples at different scales'. please feel free to edit the question.

Comment: No thanks; it's your question to ask. If you want to rewrite the question completely, that would be fine too.